# incrementing without for loop

Tags: c#, oop, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following code where I want to create a number of Goalkeeper objects, then a number of Defender objects, then Midfielders and so on.
My intention was to have the i integer increment after each object is created and use if statements to check what value i was and assign a player type accordingly.

Presently, I'm getting all my objects back as Goalkeeper objects, meaning the i is not incrementing. Any ideas how i can solve this?

```
//create different types of player
int i = 0;


if (i < 2)
{
    i+=1;
    //create gk
    p = new Goalkeeper(fname, lname, saves, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);
}
else if (i >= 2 && i < 9)
{
    i++;
    //create d
    p = new Defender(fname, lname, headerswon, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);
}
else if (i >= 9 && i < 16)
{
    i++;
    //crete mf
    p = new Midfielder(fname, lname, passsuccessrate, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);
}
else
{
    i++;
    //create striker
    p = new Striker(fname, lname, shotsontarget, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);
}

return p; //return the randomly generated player
```

Comment: This code will only ever create one object (depending of the value of i, which is always going to be 0) and then return that one object. Sounds like you need a static variable i.

Comment: Do you have any outer loop surrounding these loops. If yes, make sure you are not initialising i = 0 each time inside that

Comment: This doesn't look like the full code. You set `i` to `0` at the top so only the first `if` would ever get entered before you return.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem is I'm initializing i to 0 so its set to zero each time it runs. I have a window load method which runs this code 20 times  and populates an array with different players. So where to initialize i?

Comment: You may want to declare `i` outside the method and pass it in as a parameter, or alternatively instead of calling the method 20 times call it once and change it to return the whole array at once.

Answer (score 5):

You need a loop, otherwise the whole `if` branch structure is only checked once.

Why are you loop-averse? With a loop, it's pretty simple:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i)
{
    Player p;

    if (i < 2)
        p = new GoalKeeper(...);
    else if (i < 9)
        p = new Defender(...);
    else if (i < 16)
        p = new Midfielder(...);
    else
        p = new Striker(...);

    players.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: I'm not loop averse. Thanks!

Comment: @GerMc ...but your question says specifically, "...without for loop"

Answer (score 0):

Make i static

//create different types of player

static int i = 0;

```
            if (i < 2)
            {
            i+=1;
            //create gk
            p = new Goalkeeper(fname, lname, saves, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

        }
            else if (i >= 2 && i < 9)
            {
            i++;
            //create d
            p = new Defender(fname, lname, headerswon, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

            }
            else if (i >= 9 && i < 16)
            {
            i++;
            //crete mf
            p = new Midfielder(fname, lname, passsuccessrate, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

        }
            else
            {
            i++;
            //create striker
            p = new Striker(fname, lname, shotsontarget, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

        }



            return p; //return the randomly generated player
```

Comment: @DonatPants variable i will not be reinitialized on every call of the method as it is static now

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add, the return is where i'm having the issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I pass an int from the calling method  . Thanks all!

```
private Player GetRandomPlayer(int count)
            {

                    Player p; //create new player

                //calculate various stats using random
                int tackles = rand.Next(0, 20);
                int assists = rand.Next(0, 3);
                int goals = rand.Next(0, 3);
                int  minutesplayed = rand.Next(0, 90);
                int saves = rand.Next(0,30);
                int headerswon = rand.Next(0, 20);
                int passsuccessrate = rand.Next(0, 100);
                int shotsontarget = rand.Next(0, 25);
                string fitness = "Fit";

                //create random player names from the names data declared earlier
                string fname = firstnames[rand.Next(0, firstnames.Length)];
                string lname = lastnames[rand.Next(0, lastnames.Length)];

                //2gk, 7d,7m,4 striker

                //create different types of player





                    if (count < 2)
                    {

                        //create gk
                        p = new Goalkeeper(fname, lname, saves, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

                    }
                    else if (count < 9)
                    {

                        //create d
                        p = new Defender(fname, lname, headerswon, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

                    }
                    else if (count < 16)
                    {

                        //crete mf
                        p = new Midfielder(fname, lname, passsuccessrate, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //create striker
                        p = new Striker(fname, lname, shotsontarget, tackles, assists, goals, minutesplayed, fitness);

                    }



                    return p; //return the randomly generated player





        }
```